# Ruby записать хеш в хеш

Tags: ruby, хеширование

У меня есть хеш, в который записаны данные о заказе из примера ниже:

**Delivery information**

```
First name: Job
Last name: Clufer
Company: WMRMC
Street: 133 s. mountain ave 
City: springerville
State: Arizona
Zip: 85955
Country: United States of America
Phone: 928-323-7664
```

**Additional information**

```
IP: 74.44.236.92
Language:en
```

Мне нужно, что бы эти данные были связаны c категорией, к которой они относятся, т.е по ключу к примеру additional information я могу найти ключ
IP: и узнать его значение. 
Как это организовать?

Answer (score 1):

**Можно так:**

- создать массив хэшей (этих вот карточек)
- создать хэш рубрикаторов, элементы которого хэши массивов, элеметы которого - порядковые номера из предыдущего пункта

Тогда использовать можно примерно так:

```
$array = $hash['Country']['USA'] & $hash['Zip']['85955']
```

Это даст массив индексов тех "карточек", которые **одновременно** относятся к USA и имеют ZIP-код, равный 85955.

Впрочем, об операциях с массивами можно почитать отдельно, например, [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5678108/how-can-i-get-the-intersection-union-and-subset-of-arrays-in-ruby).